# Hi, I have a probability problem :)

Tags: probability

I wanna know about the exact answer of the question below, given three possible solutions.

(Q) Suppose K identical boxes contain n balls numbers 1 through n. One ball is drawn each box. What is the probability that m is the largest number drawn?

(A1) Defining events A1={drawn numbers are less than or equal to m}, 
                     A2={drawn numbers are equal to m}, 
                     A3={drawn numbers are greater than m}
     P(A1)=m/n, P(A2)=1/n, P(A3)=0;

```
 Viewing this as a multinomial series
 P(k) = (k!/(k-1)!1!0!)(P(A1)^(k-1))*(1!)(P(A2)^1)^1
             = km^(k-1)/n^k
```

(Ans2) Defining events A1={drawn numbers are less than or equal to m},
                     A2={drawn numbers are less than m},
     P(A1)=m/n, P(A2)=(m-1)/n;

```
 Then, P(k) = (m/n)^k - ((m-1)/n)^k = (m^k-(m-1)^k)/n^k
```

(Ans3) Considering this as a combination with repetition,
     P(k) = (mHk - (m-1)Hk) / nHk

Would you help me out here to select the best description to the answer?
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show how to calculate the answer.

The largest ball is $m$ if two things happen: All balls are $\le m$ **and** not all balls are $\le m-1$.

For any particular box, the probability that the ball we draw from it is $\le m$ is $\frac{m}{n}$. By independence, the probability that **all** the balls are $\le m$ is $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k$.

Similarly, the probability that all the balls are $\le m-1$ is  $\left(\frac{m-1}{n}\right)^k$.

The event "all balls are $\le m-1$" is a *subset* of the event "all balls are $\le m$."

It follows that the probability that $m$ is the largest number drawn is  $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k- \left(\frac{m-1}{n}\right)^k$.

Note that possibly more than one of the numbers drawn is numbered $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, Andre. If I ask for some more, could you explain why Ans 1 and 3 from my question cannot be valid?

Comment: For the first, $k-1$ numbers $\le m$ and $1$ number equal to $m$ grossly overcounts. For example it double-counts the cases where we have $m$ from the first box and also the third. Combination with repetition is irrelevant, the various combinations counted in the denominator are not equally likely.

Comment: You are welcome.